# Sql para contagem de parcelas

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela de boletos de clientes.
Os campos significantes são os seguintes:

```
| vencimento | data_pagamento | valor_pago |
```

Preciso fazer uma consulta que me retorne:

- A quantidade de parcelas vencidas não pagas;
- A quantidade de parcelas pagas;
- A quantidade de parcelas não pagas que ainda não venceram;

Estou tentando dessa forma:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN vencimento < NOW() AND data_pagamento IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'VENCIDAS',
COUNT(CASE WHEN data_pagamento IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'PAGAS',
COUNT(CASE WHEN vencimento >= NOW() AND data_pagamento IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'A VENCER'
FROM boletos WHERE cliente = 12345;
```

Porém não me retorna os valores corretos.
Existe algum meio melhor ?
O que estou fazendo de errado ao utilizar `CASE WHEN` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `COUNT` que está a utilizar vai sempre devolver **1**, seja `COUNT(1)` ou `COUNT(0)` ou mesmo `COUNT(1000)`, por isso é que não está a dar os resultados esperados.

A solução passa por utilizar o `SUM`, para que seja somado **1** sempre que a condição se verificar e **0** em caso contrário:

```
SELECT      cliente
        ,   SUM(CASE WHEN vencimento < NOW() AND data_pagamento IS NULL     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'VENCIDAS'
        ,   SUM(CASE WHEN data_pagamento IS NOT NULL                        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'PAGAS'
        ,   SUM(CASE WHEN vencimento >= NOW() AND data_pagamento IS NULL    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'A VENCER'
FROM        boletos 
GROUP BY    cliente
ORDER BY    cliente
```

Se pretender filtrar por cliente basta adicionar a cláusula `WHERE`:

```
SELECT      cliente
        ,   SUM(CASE WHEN vencimento < NOW() AND data_pagamento IS NULL     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'VENCIDAS'
        ,   SUM(CASE WHEN data_pagamento IS NOT NULL                        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'PAGAS'
        ,   SUM(CASE WHEN vencimento >= NOW() AND data_pagamento IS NULL    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'A VENCER'
FROM        boletos 
WHERE       cliente = 12345
GROUP BY    cliente
```

Comment: É necessário esse `group by` ou `order by` ao filtrar apenas por um cliente ?

Comment: O `ORDER BY` só faz sentido se não filtrar por um cliente. O `GROUP BY` tem sempre de existir por causa da coluna `cliente` que está no `SELECT`, mas se a retirar da consulta pode também remover o `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Deve ter um jeito melhor de fazer, eu faria com CTE no Oracle (que é o que eu uso) mas no MySQL eu tentaria algo assim:

```
select (select count('X') from boletos where vencimento < '2019-01-23' AND data_pagamento IS NULL and cliente = 12345),
   (select count('X') from boletos where data_pagamento IS NOT NULL and cliente = 12345),
   (select count('X') from boletos where vencimento >= '2019-01-23' AND data_pagamento IS NULL and cliente = 12345) from dual
```